# How to play music in Thread on Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-runonuithread

I am trying to write code in Android to play music. But i am starting the music in a thread so music is breaking and i need to play the music in thread because i have receive the music name through a Bluetooth socket.

So , the thread will keep listening the socket , to get the updated Music file name. But while playing the music it's breaking and not playing properly.

**MyCode:**

```
package com.example.musicexample;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btnPlay;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
Thread canThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.a);

     btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            canThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {


                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {

                                    if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                        mPlayer.stop();
                                        mPlayer.reset();
                                        try {
                                            mPlayer.prepare();
                                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.a);
                                    }

                                    mPlayer.start();

                                }
                            });

                    }

                }

            });

            canThread.start();
        }
    });
} }
```

This is the above code , please let me know , how can i play the music properly in a Thread?

Comment: what is a "while" loop for in a background thread?

Comment: to receive data from Bluetooth socket...

Comment: i see only MediaPlayer is created and started over and over again..

Comment: yes , the data will come continuously.... variously... like a , b ,c ... these are the music notes. So , when the notes will come the music will play like a piano. So , The mediaplayer object is dynamic in this case.